# Holomorphic line projection map in projective space.

Tags: complex-analysis, projective-geometry, riemann-surfaces, projective-space

Suppose we have a line $L$ in the projective space $ \mathbb{CP}^2$ and we choose a point $R \in \mathbb{CP}^2$, such that $R \notin  L$. For any other point $P \in \mathbb{CP}^2$, we define $L_{PR}$ to be the line  through $P$ and $R$.  Now we define the following map:
$$
\phi: \mathbb{CP}^2 \setminus {\{R\}} \to L, \ \  P \mapsto \{L \cap L_{PR}\}.  
$$

Here $\{L \cap L_{PR}\}$ is the unique intersection point of those two lines. The map $\phi$ is apparently holomorphic, but how would one go about proving that it is holomorphic?